# Change the search field in lookup dialogue

Tags: visualforce, lookup, lookup-filter

One of the objects has lookup relationship with Addresses object. The lookup dialogue, allows me to search for Addresses on Name. I however want to search on some different fields.

Accessing setup -> Customize -> Addresses -> Lookup dialogue, wont let me specify the search fields. "Search Settings -> Lookup Settings" was of no help either.

After searching the net, it seems that creating a VF page for edit/new is an option, where I've to write a page for lookup. However, is there any other way to simply select the search field rather than creating the whole new page?

Comment: You should be able to specify that you want to search all fields, no?

Comment: I cannot see "Search all fields", and In "Search Settings" either I could not see Enhanced Lookup for Addresses object.. Did I miss anything?